# Can I read new data from an open file without reopening it?

Tags: python, macos, file-io

Consider having a file `test.txt` with some random text in it.

Now we run the following code:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
f.read()
```

Now we append data onto `test.txt` from some other process. Is there some way without reopening `f` that we can `read` the new data?

This question is limited to Python, it is just short amount of code needed to get the point across.

Edit: I have tried everything I know (flushing, reading, seeking, etc) but that doesn't seem to update anything.

Edit: Since it seems that behavior is different depending on how the file is "appended to", I will give a more specific setup. I'm on OS X 10.9, and I'm trying to read `/var/log/system.log` which is written to by `syslogd`.

**Edit:** It appears I was incorrect. Using a `read` will pull new data, but if the data is small then a `flush` must be used first to be able to read it.

Comment: Any particular reason you do not want to re-open the file?

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea editing and reading the same part of the file simultaneously.

Comment: @tobias_k efficiency? If it's a large file, and I have to close and reopen it, then seek to the near the end every time a line is added, that could be a bottleneck. And also just plain curiosity...

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr There will always be only one writer in this case (syslog) so I don't see a problem.

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly? I can't think of any good reasons.

Comment: @korylprince i guess your goal is to read the log right away, right? do you work in linux? if so, there are plenty of ways that allow you handle this problem elegantly.

Comment: I have updated the question with more specifics. I'm on OS X in this case. The goal is a real time (or as close as possible) log reader that doesn't just rely on polling.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you could do a sys call to `tailf`?

Comment: @korylprince does pipe exists in OSX?

Comment: On Linux I would push toward using [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to watch for file modification (`IM_MODIFY`). Don't know if this is available on OS X. Don't know if there is a Python wrapper.

Comment: Apparently there is a [Python wrapper around FSEvents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents/0.2.4) available on Mac OSX. As it is callback-based this might allow you to handle [`kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html) without pooling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read from `f` again, you will get more data.

```
f = open('my_file')
print(f.read())
# in bash: echo 'more data' >> my_file
print(f.read())
```

`f` is basically a file handle with a position, reading from it again will just continue to read from whatever the position currently is.

This can also be affected by *what* is modifying the file.  Many text editors will save to a separate file first, then copy over the original.  If this happens, you will not see the changes as they are in a new file.  You many be able to continue using the existing file, but as soon as you close it the OS will finalize the delete.