# python: read file continuously, even after it has been logrotated

Tags: python, file

I have a simple python script, where I read logfile continuosly (same as `tail -f`)

```
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if line:
        print line,
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

How can I make sure that I can still read the logfile, after it has been rotated by logrotate?

i.e. I need to do the same what `tail -F` would do.

I am using `python 2.7`

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, but certainly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413115/1639625

Comment: There's a recipe that does it [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577968-log-watcher-tail-f-log/). Haven't tried it for myself, though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As long as you only plan to do this on Unix, the most robust way is probably to check so that the open file still refers to the same [i-node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) as the name, and reopen it when that is no longer the case. You can get the i-number of the file from `os.stat` and `os.fstat`, in the `st_ino` field.

It could look like this:

```
import os, sys, time

name = "logfile"
current = open(name, "r")
curino = os.fstat(current.fileno()).st_ino
while True:
    while True:
        buf = current.read(1024)
        if buf == "":
            break
        sys.stdout.write(buf)
    try:
        if os.stat(name).st_ino != curino:
            new = open(name, "r")
            current.close()
            current = new
            curino = os.fstat(current.fileno()).st_ino
            continue
    except IOError:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
```

I doubt this works on Windows, but since you're speaking in terms of `tail`, I'm guessing that's not a problem. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by keeping track of where you are in the file and reopening it when you want to read. When the log file rotates, you notice that the file is smaller and since you reopen, you handle any unlinking too.

```
import time

cur = 0
while True:
    try:
        with open('myfile') as f:
            f.seek(0,2)
            if f.tell() < cur:
                f.seek(0,0)
            else:
                f.seek(cur,0)
            for line in f:
                print line.strip()
            cur = f.tell()
    except IOError, e:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
```

This example hides errors like file not found because I'm not sure of logrotate details such as small periods of time where the file is not available.

NOTE: In python 3, things are different. A regular `open` translates `bytes` to `str` and the interim buffer used for that conversion means that `seek` and `tell` don't operate properly (except when seeking to 0 or the end of file). Instead, open in binary mode ("rb") and do the decode manually line by line. You'll have to know the file encoding and what that encoding's newline looks like. For utf-8, its `b"\n"` (one of the reasons utf-8 is superior to utf-16, btw).

Comment: thanks a lot. I am wondering though, if there is a better/more elegant solution. For instance, is there any way to check if my file descriptor `f` still points to the file `file.log` ? I presume, after the file has been logrotated, the file descriptor will still point to the old file, not to the new `file.log`

Comment: This is reasonably elegant as far as file operations are concerned IMHO. The problem is that if you keep the file open, its file descriptor continues to point to the rotated file, not the new file. You can't tell that its been aged out without rechecking the original file name. An alternate approach is to use inotify which will keep you informed of file operations. Its more complicated but is also a good approach.

Comment: Is there a way to write this function as a generator? I would like to act on the output, for various tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @tdelaney and @Dolda2000's answers, I ended up with what follows. It should work on both Linux and Windows, and also handle logrotate's `copytruncate` or `create` options (respectively copy then truncate size to 0 and move then recreate file).

```
file_name = 'my_log_file'
seek_end = True
while True:  # handle moved/truncated files by allowing to reopen
    with open(file_name) as f:
        if seek_end:  # reopened files must not seek end
            f.seek(0, 2)
        while True:  # line reading loop
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                try:
                    if f.tell() > os.path.getsize(file_name):
                        # rotation occurred (copytruncate/create)
                        f.close()
                        seek_end = False
                        break
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    # rotation occurred but new file still not created
                    pass  # wait 1 second and retry
                time.sleep(1)
            do_stuff_with(line)
```

A limitation when using `copytruncate` option is that if lines are appended to the file while time-sleeping, and rotation occurs **before** wake-up, the last lines will be "lost" (they will still be in the now "old" log file, but I cannot see a decent way to "follow" that file to finish reading it). This limitation is not relevant with "move and create" `create` option because `f` descriptor will still point to the renamed file and therefore last lines will be read before the descriptor is closed and opened again.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the downvote :) ? I'll gladly update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I made a variation of the awesome above one by @pawamoy into a generator function one for my log monitoring and following needs.

```
def tail_file(file):
    """generator function that yields new lines in a file

    :param file:File Path as a string
    :type file: str
    :rtype: collections.Iterable
    """
    seek_end = True
    while True:  # handle moved/truncated files by allowing to reopen
        with open(file) as f:
            if seek_end:  # reopened files must not seek end
                f.seek(0, 2)
            while True:  # line reading loop
                line = f.readline()
                if not line:
                    try:
                        if f.tell() > os.path.getsize(file):
                            # rotation occurred (copytruncate/create)
                            f.close()
                            seek_end = False
                            break
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        # rotation occurred but new file still not created
                        pass  # wait 1 second and retry
                    time.sleep(1)
                yield line
```

Which can be easily used like the below

```
import os, time
access_logfile = '/var/log/syslog'
loglines = tail_file(access_logfile)
for line in loglines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this proposition, I've ended up using it for a project and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'tail -F

[man tail](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

> -F     same as --follow=name --retr

> -f, --follow[={**name**|descriptor}] output appended data as the file grows;

> --retry **keep trying to open a file if it is inaccessible**

**-F** option will follow the **name** of the file not descriptor.

So when logrotate happens, it will follow the new file.

```
import subprocess

def tail(filename: str) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-F", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            yield line.decode("utf-8")
        else:
            break

for line in tail("/config/logs/openssh/current"):
    print(line.strip())
```